# Bootstrap Modals from "form method="post"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a subscribe form on my site, the [DailyPnut](http://dailypnut.com/), and I am trying to devise a way to create a modal after you submit your email address (through POST). The modal pops after you POST and shows you a further form to put your first name in. My HTML is as follows:

```
<!--HOME SECTION-->
   <section id="home">
     <div id="home">
      <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12 centered">
              <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top"=0px;>
              <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" id="peercast"></h1><br>
              <h2 class="subtitle" style="padding-bottom: 10px;margin-bottom: 15px;">"The World in a Nutshell"</h2>
              <p style="padding-left: 3em; padding-right: 3em;"><i>In a nutshell: a  strangely named daily e-mail on world affairs that will make you sound marginally more intelligent and brighten up your mornings.</i></p>
            <div class="subscribe">
                <form method="post" action="subscribe.php" role="form"> 
                <input type="email" required="" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..." class="subscribe-input" name="email" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-subscribe"     ><b>Subscribe</b></button>
     <input type="hidden" name="referr" id="referr"/>          
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    </section>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Jasen "would you, folks, visit my site?" jk =)

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to submit the form, then on the callback load the modal. Like this:

First add ids to the subscribe button so it is easy to access:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-subscribe" id="subscribe-btn">...
```

Do the same with email input:

```
<input id="email-input" type="email" required="" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..." class="subscribe-input" name="email" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">...
```

Then use jquery to bind to the click event:

```
$('#subscribe-btn').on('click', doSubscribe);
```

Finally create the `doSubscribe` function that gets called on the button click (note this needs to be declared before you bind to the click event, so this code would go before the previous code):

```
var doSubscribe = function(e) {

    //stop the browser form submit
    e.preventDefault();

    //grab the form data
    var data = {
        email: $('#email-input').val(),
        referr: $('#referr').val()
    }
    $.post('subscribe.php',data,function(response) {
        //Not sure what your php script is returning 
        //json is good and it should indicate success or failure
        //so lets say you are returning a json object with a success flag
        if(response.success) {
            //use jquery to open the modal
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        } else {
            //display error message to user
            alert("Error subscribing");
        }
    },'json');
}
```

That code will probably need a few tweaks to work with what you have but it should be the basic idea of what you need. Good luck!